# Как отсортировать данные для обучения нейросети

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети

Я начал изучать нейросети на python3 и пытаюсь написать простую нейронку для распознавание цифр. Данные для обучения скачал [с THE MNIST DATABASE](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

Доставать случайную цифру я могу так:

```py
from mnist import MNIST
import random

mndata = MNIST('samples')
images, labels = mndata.load_training()

index = random.randrange(0, len(images))
print(mndata.display(images[index]))
```

Но так я получаю случайную цифру. Можно ли как-то получать конкретную цифру?

Comment: Смотрите в документации модуля `mnist` https://pypi.org/project/python-mnist/. Укажите используемую библиотку, в том же `sklearn` уже есть поддержка MNIST, так что этот модуль `mnist` вам не нужен будет

Comment: @dIm0n Спасибо, я только сейчас догадался посмотреть на список ```labels```. там храниться информация о получаемом числе. Этого мне хватит.

Comment: Дайте ответ на свой вопрос, чтобы он не оставался без ответа. Также не забывайте принимать ответы на другие свои вопросы